# Unable to delete some csv file conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get some tabular content from a webpage and write the same in a csv file. What I wish to do now is let my script write the content in a csv file only if the table (visible as `Top Mutual Fund Holders`) is available in that page otherwise it will remove the csv file that has been created.

The table is avaible in this [webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/holders?p=FB).

The table I'm looking for is not available in this [webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UBER/holders?p=UBER).

This is my try:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UBER/holders?p=UBER"

def get_mutual_fund(soup):
    datalist = []
    for items in soup.select_one("h3:contains('Top Mutual Fund Holders')").find_next_sibling().select("table tr"):
        data = [item.text for item in items.select("th,td")]
        datalist.append(data)
    return datalist

def get_records(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        item_one = get_mutual_fund(soup_obj)
    except AttributeError: 
        item_one = ""

    if item_one:
        writer.writerows(item_one)
    else:
        os.remove("mutual_fund.csv")
    return item_one

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("mutual_fund.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for elem in get_records(url):
            print(elem)
```

I've tried with the link that do not have that table. However, it throws the following error

```
while deleting the csv file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\demo.py", line 33, in <module>
    for elem in get_records(url):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\demo.py", line 27, in get_records
    os.remove("mutual_fund.csv")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'mutual_fund.csv'
```

***How can I delete the csv file when the tabular content is not present?***

Comment: Terminated any process which is accessing the csv file and try again. Or if you are reading from Python, close the opened file. I think you asked a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: you should not write from within the `get_records` function using global `writer` variable. it should return the records (if any) and only then open the file for writing.

Comment: Oh yeah I was dumb, @buran 's suggestion is right. The process which is accessing the csv is _exactly_ the global writer. You cannot delete the file when you are writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually deleting the file when it is open to write.

You should change your main function accordingly.

```
def get_records(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        item_one = get_mutual_fund(soup_obj)
    except AttributeError: 
        item_one = None
    return item_one


if __name__ == '__main__':
    delete_file= False
    with open("mutual_fund.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        try:
            for elem in get_records(url):
                print(elem)    
        except TypeError:
            delete_file=True
    if delete_file:
        os.remove("mutual_fund.csv")
```

Comment: @yadavanklit, and what's the purpose to write in the file when you will delete it immediately (that in the case when there IS something in it)? :-)

Comment: @buran how about this?

Comment: the whole idea of the OP to write from within the function is breach of encapsulation. they need to rethink how they retrieve data and how they write to file. everything else (i.e. workarounds to accommodate their approach to this problem) is waste of time

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your existing logic as it is and delete the file when the content within csv is nothing then the following should work:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/holders?p=FB"
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UBER/holders?p=UBER"

def get_mutual_fund(soup):
    datalist = []
    for items in soup.select_one("h3:contains('Top Mutual Fund Holders')").find_next_sibling().select("table tr"):
        data = [item.text for item in items.select("th,td")]
        datalist.append(data)
    return datalist

def get_records(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        item_one = get_mutual_fund(soup_obj)
    except AttributeError: 
        item_one = ""

    if item_one:
        writer.writerows(item_one)
    else:
        f.close()
        os.remove('mutual_fund.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("mutual_fund.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        get_records(url)
```